# ApiController with CORS does not like Anonymous requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm hosting an ASP.NET MVC project in Azure web apps. 
In this project I'm using an `ApiController` to serve data to a client program.

This Api controller has a method defined as such:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/search")]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class CompanyDataController : APIController
{
    [Route("companies")]
    public string CompanySearch(string request)
    {
        return "well hello there beautiful";
    }
}
```

When I try to make requests to this controller after its been published to Azure I get this error:

> "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'."

I can access the rest of the website without issue.

I have tried to allow anonymous access with a few variations of this in `<system.web>`:

```
<authentication mode="None" />
<authorization>
  <allow users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

But that has made no difference.. any bright ideas?

Comment: If you remove `[AllowAnonymous]` from the controller it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link I posted in comments above... (wouldn't let me mark this as duplicate since the answer below wasn't marked as an answer!)

Since there is already an existing custom authorization filter on the class/controller level, therefore, to override a specific action handler (the method) and have it work without any authorization filters, we need to override the filter at the controller/class level. So adding the `OverrideAuthorization` filter did the trick. Now `AllowAnonymous` will be to do its magic.

```
[Route("api/accounts/{accountNumber}/GetX")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[OverrideAuthorization]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetX(string accountNumber)
{
    // Process     
    // ..
    // ..
}
```